# Spring WS Invalid Content Type

Tags: spring, types

I have a Spring WS client. I generated the WSDL stubs via wsimport.

When I try to send a request, I get a Invalid Content-type exception:

> SEVERE: SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. Could be an error message instead of a SOAP message
>   Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?; nested exception is com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?

Is this an indication that the message I sent has an invalid content-type or the response I receive has an invalid content-type? If it's on the client side, how do I set up the content-type?

I tried mocking the web service via Soap UI. I'm able to send and receive correct response.

Edit:

On my log, it's shown that the request is sent:

> DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent] - Sent request

Then I get that exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved.

It turns out I was NOT sending any SOAP content. The SOAP header is set correctly. But the SOAP body is empty. To resolve the issue I had to attach the content that I'm requesting.

Before:

```
GetDeletedRequest request = new GetDeletedRequest();
JAXBElement res = (JAXBElement) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request, new WebServiceMessageCallback() {...}
```

After:

```
GetDeletedRequest request = new GetDeletedRequest();
request.setGetDeletedFilter(deleteFilter); // This is the content that I'm missing!
JAXBElement res = (JAXBElement) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request, new WebServiceMessageCallback() {...}
```

This mistake was overlooked by me because I was focus on porting an AXIS 1.x client implementation to a Spring WS implementation.

Some people, including Arjen Poustma, suggested to use tcpmon to sniff what's being sent. I didn't manage to configure and run it correctly (that's another unrelated issue). But this gave me an idea to inspect first what's being sent by my application.

I looked around and saw a similar problem in the Spring Forums about the invalid content type at [WS Client using JAXB for marshalling](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=64907). The last poster suggested to use the CommonsHttpMessageSender, just like the example he provided at [Web Service Client with Spring-WS](http://justcompiled.blogspot.com/2010/11/web-service-client-with-spring-ws.html) (which is a good one). With the CommonsHttpMessageSender it was able to print out my whole SOAP envelope:

```
<property name="messageSender">
     <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender" />
</property>
```

I'm documenting here my experiences because I know one day there will be another guy like me who will be having this same problem.